# /vagrant not populated with files

Tags: vagrant

I have Vagrant (1.7.4) configured with the default configuration from `vagrant init` using the latest version of VirtualBox (5.0.16 r105871) on OS X (10.11.4) and the latest `ubuntu/trusty64` box version (v20160323.0.0).

My VM has the matching version of guest additions, but I can't seem to get the shared `/vagrant` directory to work. The `/vagrant/` directory exists on the VM, but if I run `ls` on it it's completely empty. If I `touch` a file it appears on the guest in `/vagrant` but does not sync back to the project folder on my machine, and disappears on reboot. The VirtualBox GUI shows the shared folder:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kYR8.png

EDIT: Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on 
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   sudo apt-get update
  #   sudo apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your `Vagrantfile`, or at the very least the sync folders portions of it.

Comment: @BrianMorton It's the default but I've added it to the post.

Comment: so if you create a file from guest, its not visible on host - thats weird. it disappears on reboot its normal as vagrant recreates the shared folder. 2 things to check: 1. can you create a file from host, is it visible in the VM ? 2. can you run the VM directly from virtual box ? is the same happening ? the screenshot looks good and shared folder looks correctly setup;

Comment: @FrédéricHenri The shared folder isn't working - the Vagrantfile is in the root of my project and should be filled with files, but it's empty. If I create a file on the guest, it isn't visible on the host. I get the same results running it directly from VirtualBox.

Comment: What happens if you boot the machine with `vagrant up --debug` and have a look at the output to see if there are any issues relating to synced folders. You can also output this information to a file to grep/search it: `vagrant up --debug > vagrantlog.txt`

Comment: @BrianMorton I can't see anything suggested an issue with shared folders, but here are the relevant log entries: https://gist.github.com/defectivebit/7a2972db388da102fd21ff0c7913477f

Comment: Very interesting. The log you posted was obviously edited - can you post the output of a normal `vagrant up` ? What I'm looking for is the lines around `==> default: Mounting shared folders...` to see if it even tries to mount the `/vagrant` directory. A next step might be trying to recreate this box in a separate directory (eg. `mkdir -p ~/tmp && cd ~/tmp && vagrant init` etc) to see if you have the same problem on a fresh box.

Comment: @BrianMorton No luck, unfortunately. Here is the relevant output:


    `==> default: Mounting shared folders...`
       `default: /vagrant => /Users/defectivebit/Code/md-wellness-apps`


I tried it in a new directory, making sure to delete the `.vagrant` directory and it still gives the same result.

Comment: I'm pretty much out of guesses... Try leaving vagrant out of the mix, and creating a new VM in the VB GUI to see if shared folders work there. This is all under the assumption you actually have Guest Additions for VB installed btw...

Comment: @BrianMorton I just installed the desktop GUI version of Ubuntu 15.10 in a VM, installed the guest additions and couldn't even mount the directory, so I guess I'll be doing a bit of digging. The Vagrant VM did have the correct version of guest additions.

Comment: Well it seems like we've at least ruled vagrant out as a problem, since you can't even get shared folders working in straight VBox. Perhaps open another question about why you can't get shared folders to work in VBox with a 15.10 guest - if that gets solved, this issue will also probably be resolved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've figured out what the issue is - while the `/vagrant` directory existed on the machine, the shared folder was not being automatically mounted by VirtualBox, despite the auto-mount feature being set to on in the GUI, and the debug output saying that it had indeed been mounted.

Running `sudo mount -t vboxsf vagrant /vagrant` manually solves the issue. I put this line into the prestart script for my upstart job to start my server.

Comment: This worked on Terminal, via. MacOS 10.12.5. Thank you!!

Comment: Worked in PowerShell on Windows 10

Answer (score 5):

This is more likely to happen if the VM was shutdown or rebooted from within the VM.

Halt the VM using "vagrant halt" and start the VM again using "vagrant up". This is should automatically mount it under /vagrant