# Why is the default Vagrant shared folder empty?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

The `/vagrant` directory is empty. It should contain the workspace where my Vagrantfile is located. I can `cd /vagrant`, but it's empty.

---

**Vagrantfile**

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = '2'
VAGRANT_BOX_NAME = 'nomades.local'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'bento/centos-6.7'
  config.vm.box_check_update = false
  config.vm.hostname = VAGRANT_BOX_NAME

  config.vm.define VAGRANT_BOX_NAME do |dev|
    dev.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |v|
      v.name = VAGRANT_BOX_NAME
      v.memory = 512
      v.cpus = 2
      v.gui = true
      v.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--ioapic', 'on', '--vram', '16']
    end

    # Réseau (penser à configurer son /etc/hosts pointant vers cette ip)
    dev.vm.network 'private_network', ip: '192.168.12.2'

    # In order to use VPN
    # dev.vm.network 'public_network', ip: '172.32.0.101'

    # Provision
    dev.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.groups = {
          'vagrant' => [VAGRANT_BOX_NAME],
          'servers' => [VAGRANT_BOX_NAME],
      }
      ansible.playbook = 'provision/provision.yml'
      ansible.sudo = true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/vagrant not populated with files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270066/vagrant-not-populated-with-files)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens when vagrant can't modify `/etc/fstab` and tries to mount the current working directory from the host. Make sure it has permissions to mount the directory.

Run this on the Vagrant guest VM, then logout.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup
```

Run this on the host.

```
$ sudo vagrant reload
$ vagrant ssh
```

Comment: Indeed It was a sudo issue, your solution work, thanks!

Comment: Thanks ! In Windows you don't need to run as administrator the `vagrant reload`

Comment: For me on MacOS, just the `vagrant reload` on the host is enough to get the folders to sync again.

Comment: By the way, on linux in 2024,  this no longer works, primarily because /etc/init.d/vboxadd does not exist

Answer (score 2):

This issue happened to me after manually rebooting the VM (i.e. `sudo reboot`).

Restarting the machine from the host solved the problem for me:

```sh
$ vagrant halt
$ vagrant up
```

Comment: This actually helped whereas restarting my host machine didn't :/

Answer (score 1):

you need to define below line in the vagrantfile,  **.** means current directory

`config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"`

Comment: AFAIK there is no extra definition necessary for the /vagrant directory, because it is automatically mapped to current directory. The config says, you need to do (only?) if you need "additional" shares.

Comment: While it's true that the docs say that you don't need to do this, it does work for me.  I think the core problem is that my SSH is not configured in a way that's compatible with the automatic ssh connection and I had to switch to using a login and password.  This meant that somehow the default synced files don't get registered.  So doing the above got them registered.